# How can I loop over a specific field in Json API data in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to get a specific field from my json data to afterwards loop over it and get the values inside.
Json data is like:

```
 "Cost_of_living": [{"_id": {"$oid": "623f0608ace09073a556aaf2"}, "good_id": 1, "item_name": "Price per square meter to Buy Apartment Outside of City Center", "category_id": 1, "category_name": "Buy Apartment", "min": 2373.44, "avg": 3133.32, "max": 4127.72, "measure": "money", "currency_code": "EUR", "Ciudad": "Barcelona", "Pa\u00eds": "Spain", "update_date": 1648293908478, "cityID": 0}, {"_id": {"$oid": "623f0608ace09073a556aaf3"}, "good_id": 2, "item_name": "Price per square meter to Buy Apartment in City Center", "category_id": 1, "category_name": "Buy Apartment", "min": 4127.72, "avg": 4968.95, "max": 6191.59, "measure": "money", "currency_code": "EUR", "Ciudad": "Barcelona", "Pa\u00eds": "Spain", "update_date": 1648293908478, "cityID": 0}, {"_id": {"$oid": "623f0608ace09073a556aaf4"}, "good_id": 3, "item_name": "International Primary School, Yearly for 1 Child", "category_id": 2, "category_name": "Childcare", "min": 6191.59, "avg": 8643.94, "max": 14859.81, "measure": "money", "currency_code": "EUR", "Ciudad": "Barcelona", "Pa\u00eds": "Spain", "update_date": 1648293908478, "cityID": 0}, {"_id": {"$oid": "623f0608ace09073a556aaf5"}, "good_id": 4, "item_name": "Private Preschool or Kindergarten, Monthly for 1 Child", "category_id": 2, "category_name": "Childcare", "min": 309.58, "avg": 446.18, "max": 619.16, "measure": "money", "currency_code": "EUR", "Ciudad": "Barcelona", "Pa\u00eds": "Spain", "update_date": 1648293908478, "cityID": 0}, {"_id": {"$oid": "623f0608ace09073a556aaf6"}, "good_id": 5, "item_name": "Pair of Jeans in a Chain Store Like George, H&M, Zara, etc.", "category_id": 3, "category_name": "Clothing And Shoes", "min": 41.28, "avg": 72.11, "max": 103.19, "measure": "money", "currency_code": "EUR", "Ciudad": "Barcelona", "Pa\u00eds": "Spain", "update_date": 1648293908478, "cityID": 0},
```

What I was trying to do is:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DataTable(columns: [
        for (var item in hotelsList[index].costOfLiving!)
          DataColumn(
            label: Text(item.toString()),
          ),
```

but I am directly getting a null value.

Let's say I want to get all the values inside the tag "item_name". How would you do it ?

Comment: What's `hotelsList` and what's `index`? Based on your JSON, are you expecting `item` to be a `Map<String, dynamic>` with keys `good_id`, `item_name`, etc?

Comment: You have key/value pairs in Map! not index, if you want `item_name` you have to do like `yourMap.item_name` not index!

Comment: @mohammadesmaili index is pointing to different endpoints, so index 0 would be one endpoint pointing to let's say city "Dublin" and index 1 to another city and so on.. so my json is structured like that. I am expecting my key to be "item_name" and my value "avg". HotelList is the whole list. Cost_of_living is a child of that list.